# Operating system does not meet the minimum requirements of the language server

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, error-messaging

I installed Python 3.7.2 and VSCode 1.32.1 on Mac OS X 10.10.2. In VSCode I installed the Pyhton extension and got a message saying:

"Operating system does not meet the minimum requirements of the language server. Reverting to alternative, Jedi".

When clicking the "More" option under the message I got information indicating that I need OS X 10.12, at least.

I tried to install an older version of the extension, did some reading here and asked Google, but I'm having a hard time since I don´t really know what vocabulary to use.

My questions are: 
Will the extension work despite the error message?
Do I need to solve this, and how do I do that?

Comment: Practically? That not all of the VSCode features will work. If you are learning to code, that is probably *a good thing*. IMO, when you are learning to code, you should use as bare-bones a development environment as possible. In any case, there doesn't seem to be anything that you need to "solve".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension will work without the language server, but some thing won't work quite as well (e.g. auto-complete and some refactoring options). Basically if you remove the `"python.jediEnabled"` setting -- or set it to `false` -- and the extension works fine for you then that's the important thing. :)